# Where can I track my upvotes from community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

How can I track my daily community wiki upvotes or downvotes, except for my profile page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking of Community Wiki upvotes and Comment Upvotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/tracking-of-community-wiki-upvotes-and-comment-upvotes)