# Tracking of Community Wiki upvotes and Comment Upvotes?

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, community-wiki, recent-activity

Would it be possible to have our envelope updates not only show rep-based upvotes, but community wiki and comment upvotes as well?

I would like some finer granularity when it comes to vote tracking if possible.

Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 3):

Now that the activity dropdown has been created, this should be considered as one of the lines in there.