# Add votes on my CW posts to my summary screen

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, activity-summary

I'd like to follow up on votes on my CW posts as I do on normal ones, for cases like the [voting on the new sites brainstorming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373), or just generic CW posts.

They should appear in green (or red for downvotes) boxes with no reputation attached, like the votes look like on questions when you reached the cap, like so:

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/cw1.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/cw1.png)

If the post was turned to CW after harnessing a few votes, it should look like this:

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/cw2.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/cw2.png)

For downvotes, it should look the same but red.

Comment: +1 I've always wondered why this wasn't shown to begin with.

Comment: How would you want 3 upvotes and 2 downvotes on the same CW answer displayed?

Comment: @Dom, on two different boxes like they do on normal posts now

Comment: Hear, hear! Good show.

Comment: @Jon Did you... link the wrong post? You linked the post as a duplicate of itself. Did you perhaps mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/tracking-of-community-wiki-upvotes-and-comment-upvotes or some other similar post?

Comment: Oops! Yeah, I meant http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/tracking-of-community-wiki-upvotes-and-comment-upvotes -- copy/paste superfail on my part. @Gra

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they could just make CW votes appear in a different color than red and green on the summary screen, like yellow. That way they won't be confused with votes that don't count after the cap.

Since up or down votes on CW posts don't count towards Rep anyway, they can just show the total (up minus down) in the one yellow box, instead of adding a pair of new colored boxes (i.e. one color each for up and down CW votes).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, the idea behind the reputation tag is to show reputation. As you do not receive reputation for a CW post, I'd say it doesn't belong in the reuptation tag.

I would like to see both a votes given and received history, however.

**EDIT**

Based on Downvoter's rebuttal, I now favor adding CW votes to the *summary* page, as well as the all votes tab.

Comment: I'm talking about the summary tab, but in any case, it could go to the reputation tab, where votes that don't give reputation (because you are capped) are also shown

Comment: @Downvoter: excellent point. Tune changed.