# Do you get reputation points when people upvote an answer of yours to a community wiki question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, community-wiki

Do you get reputation points when people upvote an answer of yours to a community wiki question? From what I can tell you don't. I've been upvoted 5 times for this answer, [What should a WinForms developer know for an ASP.Net interview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642329/what-should-a-winforms-developer-know-for-an-asp-net-interview/2642366#2642366), but when I look at my stats I do not see any reputation being added. At first I thought maybe 5 people downvoted it as well, but I do not see any downvotes in my stats either. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 2):

No, community-wiki posts do not generate reputation.

Please see the FAQ here: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

The voting on community-wiki questions and answers currently do not show up in the user profile either. You can support that [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42531/add-votes-on-my-cw-posts-to-my-summary-screen) if you'd like.