# Shouldn't upvotes appear in recent activity even if they grant zero rep due to cap?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity, daily-reputation-limit

As per subject, I think you should be able to see received upvotes even if they grant no rep change.

As you can see in this (double) screenshot, there are 3 answers with upvote after the last one recorded in recent activity

[image]

Comment: Were those answers to a CW question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42531/add-votes-on-my-cw-posts-to-my-summary-screen

Comment: I don't see you hitting the rep cap on that screenshot.

Comment: @ChrisF no they weren't

Comment: @voyager well if I wasn't capped that'd be even more strange

Answer (score 1):

The "summary" tab only shows the "Top 5 Posts" (see the caption in your screen shot). I'm not really sure by what measure these items are ordered, but the posts you are missing don't seem to have made it into the top five.

To see all posts switch to the "reputation" tab.

Comment: It just seem to ignore zero-rep activities, as when I had an answer accepted (which is immune from the cap) it appeared in that list. I think that it should just show *all* recent activity, regardless of an entry giving rep or not. Seems weird that if I want to see zero-rep activity I need to go on the reputation tab.

Comment: @kemp: On the summary page always only five items are shown. If you want to see more you have to go to the other tab, no matter if those other items gave rep or not. But it *is* unintuitive that the summary page doesn't show you all information and you have to switch tabs. It can often be a source for confusion.