# answer not showing up in my recent activity

Tags: support, reputation, recent-activity

My answer shows up on my user page, but upvotes on it don't show up under recent activity:

[C++ STL: Array vs Vector: Raw element accessing performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740020/c-stl-array-vs-vector-raw-element-accessing-performance/2740064#2740064)

Other answers I posted before and after do show up. It's not community wiki. I've been past the rep cap for some time today.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47530/shouldnt-upvotes-appear-in-recent-activity-even-if-they-grant-zero-rep-due-to-ca

Comment: @ccomet: Yes, it's like that, except I have a long series of answers with votes but no points. There is just one answer conspicuously missing.

Comment: Make sure and check it by hitting the `reputation` tab, the recent activity list isn't necessarily sorted as you might think.

Comment: @Lance: Aha, thank you! If you post as an answer I'll accept it. The other question also has a similar answer, but I didn't understand… in part because the particular question that wasn't showing was both more recent and higher-voted than the ones that did appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hit the `reputation` tab, the recent activity list isn't necessarily sorted as you might think.

Comment: … ie, treat it as a random selection once the cap is hit.