# Make top 5 posts based on upvotes, not reputation earned (or at least change the phrasing)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I hit my rep cap today and I noticed something - I have one answer with 7 upvotes that earned 70 reputation and another answer with 6 upvotes that only earned 10 rep.

Looking at my summary, under the Top 5 Posts heading the post with 7/70 is at the top and the more recent post with 6/10 is missing from the list.  What follows are a couple of 2/20 answers, a 4/40 and an acc/15.

It makes more sense to me that a higher voted posts should be top rated, irrespective of the amount of reputation earned.  For instance, if I had 20 answers with 1 vote each and then posted another answer that received 20 votes but no rep, it wouldn't appear in the Top 5 Posts list.

Related:

- [Add votes on my CW posts to my summary screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42531/add-votes-on-my-cw-posts-to-my-summary-screen)