# Votes to community wiki posts aren't visible in reputation history if there are no "real" reputation events that day

Tags: bug, community-wiki, reputation-history

When analyzing [this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4614/70594) on MathOverflow Meta, I noticed that [this user's reputation history](https://mathoverflow.net/users/69642/user69642?tab=reputation) doesn't show the three upvotes to [their recent community wiki answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363901/70594); there's not even an entry without the green +x reputation label:

[image]

However, [my own reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=reputation), even when viewing while being logged in as another account, does show two recent upvotes to [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/295232).

[image]

Further analysis by Martin shows that it might be related to not having any other reputation events that day; I've checked some old posts of mine on MathOverflow and can confirm.

Comment: I originally commented on MO, but this is probably a better place. Based on what I saw in the past (while obsessively checking my reputation tab and votes on my posts), it seems that the votes on CW-posts are shown in the reputation tab only if *there is some other reputation change in the same day.* I thought that this was intentional - since this behavior existed for a long time.

Comment: Here is a feature request from 2010: [Add votes on my CW posts to my summary screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42531). The images in that post are dead, but form the description it seems that it is basically about this. And this is also related, at least tangentially: [Tracking of Community Wiki upvotes and Comment Upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1403)

Comment: This seems possibly intentional to me. I'd either make this a support question asking if it's intentional, or a feature request asking for those events to be added.

Comment: @Sonic well, hiding them altogether would make sense. They don't show up on `/reputation` either. However, showing them inconsistently like this doesn't seem [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Would "other" be a better word then "real"?

Comment: @Luuklag I'd opt for "reputation-bestowing" if it weren't too long ...